# The cookies are not store in the browser

Tags: reactjs

import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies();

```
cookies.set('jwt', "chalmeraputt");
console.log(cookies.get("jwt"));
```

I have using this code to add cookie but could not get it and also not showed in the browser also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";

function App() {
    const cookies = new Cookies();

    cookies.set("cookie", "chocolate_chip", { path: "/" });

    return <div>{cookies.get("cookie")}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

A cookie is a piece of data (key-value pairs) stored on the user’s computer by the web browser while browsing a site. Cookies are a reliable mechanism for websites to remember stateful information or record the user’s browsing activity or verify the user's identity.

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

const cookies = new Cookies();

cookies.set('jwt', 'chalmeraputt', { path: '/' });

console.log(cookies.get('jwt'));
```

Refer [this link](https://reactgo.com/react-get-cookie/)